# Self-hosted dasboard for Messenger booking bot

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Is there AIO solution that would allow me to have:

1. Dashboard/backend that I can self-host (VPS)
2. Bot and parameters to configure booking bot and prices/availability, etc...
3. Simple integration with FB account to get things rolling

The idea is simple, execution probably not:

To have ready-made script/system (any language actually) which would provide me with facebook messenger bot configuration and connection to FB account.

What for and how:

Users can book an appointment via messenger, they would be presented with choices/parameters previously configured in the self-hosted backend on some domain, upon booking completion data would be stored to backend's database and available to admin for CRUD operations. Some manual and automatic notifications should be available and thats it.

Is there anything like that available?
I dont care what programming language it uses or what the requirements are, just the price.

Easyappointments would be the closest feature vise backend to what im looking for, except for the bot part...

Thanks

Comment: There are various Chat-bot building online sites that provides services like this. You can take a look into those. Those also provides API binding. So, you can connect with your back-end via API.

Comment: Did you succeed with easyappointment and messenger bot? Or is this some kind of nice-to-have idea? simplybook.me exists but not self-hosted.